# Updating Count of Records With Specific Field Value

Tags: apex, trigger

On the Case object, I have two custom fields:

- Special__c
- SpecialCount__c

I want SpecialCount to be the total number of Case records (including the current one) that have the same value for Special

I am trying to write an APEX Trigger that will update SpecialCount for a case when:

- Its Special value is populated
- Any other record is populated with the
  same value for Special.

This is what I left off with before conceding that I needed to ask for help:

```
trigger UpdateSpecialCount on Case (before update) {

for (Case cases: Trigger.new){

   //Get the Case IDs that are already in Trigger.new
   Set<ID> caseIds = Trigger.newMap.keySet();

   //Get the value for Special
   String Special = cases.Special__c;

   //If Special is not empty, continue
   IF (!String.isEmpty(Special)){

       //If Special was previously NULL, or if SpecialCount was NULL/0; continue.

       Case oldCase = Trigger.oldMap.get(cases.ID);

       IF(!oldCase.Special__c.equals('')||cases.SpecialCount__c==NULL || cases.SpecialCount__c==0){

           //Get COUNT of cases with Special value, and store to variable
           Integer countCases = [SELECT COUNT() FROM CASE WHERE Special__c = :Special];

           //Get LIST of cases with Special value, where SpecialCount isn't correct, and ID isn't in trigger.new already
           List<Case> specialCases = [SELECT ID FROM CASE WHERE Special__c = :Special ID NOT IN :caseIds AND SpecialCount__c != :CountCases ];

           //Update cases SpecialCount for cases in trigger.new
           cases.SpecialCount__c = countCases;

           //trigger an update for that list of records not in trigger.new
           UPDATE specialCases;

       }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to track this number in the case itself?  This count is better viewed in a report of all cases, you can just let the report calculate the total.

Comment: The SpecialCount value is going to be one of a number of factors used in the calculation of a formula field that will also be on the case record.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need this data for reporting purposes, you don't need to store the count on the Case itself. Just create a Summary type report and group by `Special__c`.

---

If you do need the data on the `Case` object itself, I recommend rolling the data up to `Special__c` using [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), then pulling the value back down via formula.

First create a `Number` type field on your parent object called `Case_Count__c`. Then create a `Formula` field (also `Number`) on your `Case` object called `Special_Count__c` and have it pull in the parent value:

```
Special__r.Case_Count__c
```

Your custom `Lookup Rollup Summary` record would be something like:

- Parent Object: `Special__c`
- Relationship Field: `Special__c`
- Child Object: `Case`
- Field to Aggregate: `Id`
- Aggregate Operation: `Count`
- Aggregate Result Field: `Case_Count__c`

Comment: I've done something to this effect before, and agree it would be better.   I don't have the option due to existing setup that my superiors don't want modified at this time.

Comment: @Michael What existing setup would prohibit this setup? It's Declarative **Lookup** Rollup Summaries. You don't need a Master-Detail relationship to pursue this approach.

Answer (score 2):

If I hadn't read your comment on your question, I too would have suggested using a report for this purpose.

Adrian's suggestion of using the DLRS tool is still one that I'd consider (though it would require you to change your `Special__c` field to be a lookup to a new `Special__c` custom object that you'd need to create). It's well known, and well tested.

That said, if you truly can't make any other changes to your org's metadata, the DLRS tool simply uses *aggregate queries*, and you can write pretty much the same thing for yourself (though why re-invent the wheel if you can avoid doing so?) Since I'm guessing that you can see than my answer goes on for a while, take that as a warning that **what you're attempting to do is not simple**.

The general form of the query you would use is

```
[SELECT COUNT(Id) expressionAlias, Special__c FROM Case WHERE <some filters> GROUP BY Special__c]
```

It's the the `GROUP BY` clause that turns a query into an *aggregate* query, and once you use that, you can use aggregate functions ( `COUNT(Id)` in this case). There are some aggregate functions you can use without using `GROUP BY`, but we're not really concerned with that detail here.

Aggregate queries are handled a bit differently from normal SObjects

```
// Aggregate queries return AggregateResults
// The "count" after "COUNT(Id)" is a field alias.
// I believe you can only alias fields in an aggregate query.
// It's not required to provide an alias.
for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT COUNT(Id) count, Special__c FROM Case WHERE <some filters> GROUP BY Special__c]){
    // With AggregateResult, you are required to use .get(<field name as string literal>).
    // On top of that, ar.get() always returns things of the "Object" class, and
    //   you'll need to explicitly type-cast them to do pretty much anything with
    //   the field value.
    // If you don't provide field aliases, you'd access results of aggregate functions
    //   by their auto-generated aliases "expr<X>", where <X> starts at 0, and
    //   as is given to the leftmost aggregate function without an alias (then 
    //   the next one is "expr1", "expr2", etc... numbered from left to right
    Decimal specialCount = (Decimal)ar.get('count');
}
```

You'd need to be careful in using that, however. Limiting the values of `Special__c` that you're querying for would be a good idea. Otherwise it'd be quite easy to go over the 50,000 query rows limit. In reality, you need to be even more careful than that, because you'd need to update all the `SpecialCount__c`s of the records with one of the given values of `Special__c` and the governor limit on DML rows in a single transaction is 10,000.

On top of that, you should take precautions to make sure that you don't get yourself into an infinite loop (you are, after all, attempting to update `Case` records in a update trigger on `Case`).

The final concern I can come up with right now is that you'll need to take into consideration some nuances of the order of execution. In a `before` trigger context, the new value of `Special__c` hasn't yet made it to the database. That means that if you query for one of the records in `trigger.new`, *you'll get the old value of that field*.

As a consequence, when you perform this aggregate query, *the count you receive will be one higher than it should be for the old value of `Speical__c`, and one lower than it should be for the new value of `Special__c`*.

What follows is a rough guess of what the code you'd need to do this would look like. It is untested, and I'm not 100% certain it will work. If you're still with me at this point, **please, seriously consider creating the new custom object and using the DLRS tool instead**. Show this to your superiors if need be so that they fully understand what they are asking you to do.

```
// First thing, yes, this is a separate apex class.
// It's generally good practice to take the logic you'd normally put into triggers
//   and put them into classes instead (that you then call from your trigger), but
//   in this case, it's required for recursion control
public class CaseSpecialCounter{
    // This static variable is part of some basic recursion control.
    // Before doing any work, we need to check to make sure that we haven't
    //   already worked on this record before.
    // A simple boolean value wouldn't work if you happen to update more than 
    //   200 Cases in one shot.
    private static Set<Id> alreadyProcessed;

    // Since we'll need to know both the old and new values of Special__c, we
    //   need to pass old and new collections to this method.
    // Avoiding using trigger context variables here is a good thing.
    public void updateSpecialCounts(List<Case> oldCaseList, List<Case> newCaseList){
        // First things first, check to see if we've worked on all of these cases before
        Map<Id, Case> newCaseMap = new Map<Id,Case>(newCaseList);
        if(CaseSpecialCounter.alreadyProcessed.containsAll(caseMap.keySet()){
            // In this block, we know that there are no new records to process.
            // return early to prevent recursive work.
            return;
        }

        Map<Id, Case> oldCaseMap = new Map<Id,Case>(oldCaseList);
        // Add the Ids to the already processed set so we don't work on these 
        //   same records again.
        CaseSpecialCounter.alreadyProcessed.addAll(caseMap.keySet());

        // Let's figure out which special values we're working with
        Set<String> workingSpecials = new Set<String>();
        // We also need to know how many records are leaving one special value
        //   and going to a new value
        Map<String, Integer> losingValuesCountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> gainingValuesCountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();

        Case oldCase;
        for(Case c :newCaseList){
            workingSpecials.add(c.Special__c);
            oldCase = oldCaseMap.get(c.Id);

            // We only want to update the losingValuesCountMap if Special__c
            //   wasn't previously null
            if(oldCase.Special__c != null){
                // This is just my preferred method of populating maps in loops.
                // Put the key into the map with a default value, and leave updating
                //   the value to outside the if
                if(!losingValuesCountMap.containsKey(oldCase.Special__c)){
                    losingValuesCountMap.put(oldCase.Special__c, 0);
                }
                // Not 100% sure that this line will work as intended
                losingValuesCountMap.get(oldCase.Special__c)++;
            }

            // Similar story for the new special values
            if(c.Special__c != null){
                if(!gainingValuesCountMap.containsKey(c.Special__c)){
                    gainingValuesCountMap.put(c.Special__c, 0);
                }
                // Not 100% sure that this line will work as intended
                gainingValuesCountMap.get(c.Special__c)++;
            }
        }

        // Now we can do the aggregate query
        Map<String, Integer> newSpecialCountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT COUNT(Id) count, Special__c FROM Case WHERE Special__c IN :workingSpecials GROUP BY Special__c]){
            // It's generally a good idea to do null checks when working with
            //   results of aggregate functions
            Decimal newCount = ar.get('count') == null ? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('count');
            String specialVal = (String)ar.get('Special__c');

            // Adjust the newCount as appropriate
            if(losingValuesCountMap.containsKey(specialVal)){
                newCount -= losingValuesCountMap.get(specialVal);
            }

            if(gainingValuesCountMap.containsKey(specialVal)){
                newCount += gainingValuesCountMap.get(specialVal);
            }

            newSpecialCountMap.put(specialVal , newCount);
        }

        // Now we need to find the records that we need to update
        // We need to do this even for the Cases that were passed in to this method.
        // If you don't, then you're likely to get a "object is part of the current trigger,
        //   cannot recursively update a record from an update trigger" error.
        // Even with this, you still may run into that error
        List<Case> casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();
        for(Case c :[SELECT Id, Special__c, SpecialCount__c FROM Case WHERE Special__c IN :workingSpecials]){
            c.SpecialCount__c = newSpecialCountMap.get(c.Special__c);
        }

        // For safety, include all of the cases we're going to update in the
        //   already processed set
        Map<Id, Case> finalProcessedAdditions = new Map<Id, Case>(casesToUpdate);
        CaseSpecialCounter.alreadyProcessed.addAll(finalProcessedAdditions .keySet());

        update casesToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Now, I know I've basically provided the solution to you. I believe this code is beyond your current level of experience. Seeing this code (along with the comments) can be incredibly informative, but if you choose to use this code, know that I fully expect you to read and understand *all* of my code comments. Know further that you will probably need to make tweaks to this, and you will need to write the test class for this, and that making a new question asking for help on my code will likely be met with a downvote by me.

If you don't feel confident enough to tweak this code without asking another question here, then you shouldn't use this code. It's as much of a solution as it is a warning about the level of code required to fit your requirements.

Again, don't just copy/paste this code blindly. Use a custom object and the DLRS tool if at all possible. If you can't use the code directly, use it to convince your superiors that you really do need to rethink the problem (or at least the approach to solving it). I wouldn't necessarily show them the code (lest they think the problem is already solved, so why are you complaining?), the text description of the code should do.

Remember, you are responsible for maintaining the code you add to your org.